# Access Actionbar TextView from another fragement

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Hi im trying to access a Text View from the Action Bar, for example when a button is pressed I would like the Text View in the action bar to change. is this possible ?

the following is my code MainActivity with actionbar

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
new URLAsyncCaller().execute();
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
LinearLayout search = (LinearLayout) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById  (R.id.btn_chart);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("lastid", 1); // also puts the data into a shared
editor.commit();
TextView toptitle= (TextView)search.findViewById(R.id.tv_avtiontext);
toptitle.setText(GWave.getActiontext());`
```

Fragement B Code

```
GWave.setActiontext("Welcome To Z-Wave");
```

I have tried creating a method in the Main Activity to handle the text change but couldn't get it working. Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated .. Thank you.

Comment: PS: Your code is very unstructured. Please consider making some private methods that you can call to get the work done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `TextView` in your `ActionBar` has an id `action_text`,
in the `Fragment`, do this:

```
TextView actionText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_text);
```

Et Voilà! You are done! :)